# What's the turnaround in Glorious by Ella Henderson?

Tags: chord-progressions

I've got these chords in Ab for Glorious by Ella Henderson:

ii V I vi

I can't figure out what the little turnaround or harmonized arpeggio is at the end of the fourth bar of the progression (also atthe intro).

I think it starts on the vi and it sounds a bit pentatonic but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?